# http GET and PUT binary data (CouchDB attachments) from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rest, couchdb, blob

I need to download, edit and upload (via HTTP PUT) binary blobs to CouchDB (as attachments) from a browser javascript CouchApp.

My google-fu fails me to find anything even remotely similar to this :/

Current solution involves using Silverlight, and I wish to go plain-js on modern browsers (Safari, Mobile Safari (iOS), IE 9, Opera 11 etc)

There is a solution for uploading data in Chrome ( [Post binary data cross domain in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026003/post-binary-data-cross-domain-in-javascript) ) , but I don't want to stick to that particular browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is a bit inconvenient for dealing with binary data, but it should still be possible.

The simplest way to do this is to use CouchDB's base64 version of the attachments. You can [get attachments inline in a document](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Getting_Attachments_With_a_Document), and then store them back as [inline attachments](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Inline_Attachments).

You can use any Javascript base64 library to decode them in the browser. CouchDB includes one as part of its Futon application. You can retrieve it from `/_utils/script/base64.js`.

Comment: Thanks! Missed that. Well, working with large attachments would be awkward at least, but the bare-minimum scenario (editing the code of a CouchApp from another CouchApp) seems to be OK.

Comment: Well, uploads work fine, but downloads always result in multipart data even if i don't specify Accept: headers :(

Comment: Well, enabling JSONP still does not do the trick. But, I consider that a CouchDB bug, so your answer remains valid.